# How to post complex Json data (body) using restsharp?

Tags: restsharp

I hope you are doing well !!

I need to do a post request using restsharp, the body to be added to request is given below. This is bit complicated than the post request I have done before.

**Complex Post for which I request assistance:**

```
{
  "contextInfoId": "string",
  "userId": "string",
  "specificOs": "string",
  "buildPlatform": "string",
  "deviceName": "string",
  "deviceId": "string",
  "token": "string",
  "loginInfo": {
    "loginInfoId": "string",
    "loginDate": "2019-03-14T06:21:39.693Z"
  }
}
```

---

### **This issue for me here is the way 'loginInfo:' has to be provided**

I have added basic post body to request using below code:

```
//Add json data/body
request.AddJsonBody(new { buProfileId ="1", divisionNames = "IDC", businessUnitNames = "XYZ", processGroupNames = "ABC", systemOrProjectName = "Test", customername = "User" });
```

The above C# code work fine for a body like below.

```
{
  "buProfileId": "string",
  "divisionNames": "string",
  "businessUnitNames": "string",
  "processGroupNames": "string",
  "systemOrProjectName": "string",
  "customername": "string"
}
```

Could someone please let me know how to achieve the complex post operation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create an json object and assign your value to it, then you can serialize the json and send in the body

```
public class LoginInfo
{
    public string loginInfoId { get; set; }
    public DateTime loginDate { get; set; }
}

public class Context
{
    public string contextInfoId { get; set; }
    public string userId { get; set; }
    public string specificOs { get; set; }
    public string buildPlatform { get; set; }
    public string deviceName { get; set; }
    public string deviceId { get; set; }
    public string token { get; set; }
    public LoginInfo loginInfo { get; set; }
}

public IRestResponse Post_New_RequestType(string context, string user_ID, string Specific_Os, string Build_Platfrom, string Device_Name, string device_Id, string Token_Value, string login_infoId, DateTime Login_Date)
        {

            Context tmp = new Context();
            tmp.contextInfoId = context;
            tmp.userId = user_ID;
            tmp.specificOs = Specific_Os;
            tmp.buildPlatform = Build_Platfrom;
            tmp.deviceName = Device_Name;
            tmp.deviceId = device_Id;
            tmp.token = Token_Value;
            tmp.loginInfo.loginInfoId  = login_infoId;
            tmp.loginInfo.loginDate = Login_Date;


            string json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(tmp);
            var Client = new RestClient(HostUrl);
            var request = new RestRequest(Method.POST);
            request.Resource = string.Format("/api/example");
            request.AddParameter("application/json", json, ParameterType.RequestBody);
            IRestResponse response = Client.Execute(request);
            return response;
}
```